# Best pattern for elevated lava or water?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

Related to [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/39442/how-can-i-make-an-automatic-egg-harvester-in-minecraft), I am trying to create an elevated surface where I can put water. The surface below is made up of ladders/signs to keep the water flowing down, but still allows items (e.g., eggs) to pass through.

What is the optimal pattern for the ways in which the ladders would be laid out in, say, an 8x8 square area?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you use signs, you can place signs on other signs and just cover the area needed. There is no way to use less than 1 sign per block though.

[image: Signs placed on signs]

**Edit:** As of 1.8, you have shift-right-click to place signs on other signs.

Comment: Amazing!! I had no idea...

Comment: Despite repeatedly trying, I have never been able to place a sign on another sign. Are you using mods?

Comment: @Fambida No, no mods are required. I don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: You have to right-click on the actual sign (there should be a box highlighting it, like with any other block), not the block space it ends up occupying. Does that help?

Comment: gates can also be used for this.  They're a little annoying to place, since you must first have a 'floor' to place them on, which you can subsequently remove, but I think they take a little less material than signs